# What are the advantages of using a 3rd party product review aggregator compared to self managing reviews?

Tags: ecommerce, recommendations, user-reviews

We want to start collecting Product Reviews on our site but I don't know if it's best that we use a 3rd party product review aggregator like ShopperApproved or if we should manage our own reviews directly from within our eCommerce Store. We plan to display our reviews in Google Shopping & implement Rich Snippets both of which are built into ShopperApproved which makes things easy but I don't only want the easiest solution but the smartest solution. What's the best decision here?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.. do you want control of your reviews or allow anyone to leave one even if they never did business with you? Keep in mind the most "helpful" reviews on most review sites are sadly, the bad ones. Between fake reviews and discount for product reviews, the whole review idea is losing credibility.

What I have told clients who sell a product is to simply send an email after point of sale with a simple 4 field form.

1. Were you satisfied with the product
2. Were you pleased with the customer service (if applicable)
3. If any, what would you change about the shopping experience
4. Would you be willing to leave us a review below

This way you get a real feedback, and makes the client feel you cared for their thoughts and opinion after the sale, not just from a pre-sales aspect.

Then post your reviews to your site. Dedicate a review page with proper heading and meta data, so if someone looks for reviews, they find it and you keep clients on your site.

Clients have loved it so far.